# Asymmetricity vs asymmetry, is there any difference in meaning or usage?

Tags: meaning, differences

Is there any difference in meaning or usage between asymmetricity and asymmetry?

Comment: Asymmetricity seems to just be a very odd synonym of asymmetry; both mean an absence of symmetry, and the only definition of the former I could find was on Wiktionary. It's not listed in any dictionaries that I can see.

Comment: @JohnClifford Glad that Asymmetry is no longer an adjective ;) and you deleted previous comment. Thanks for this info though.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, I was looking at "asymmetric" and got confused for a second.

Comment: @JohnClifford No worries man. I am kidding.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where exactly did you see the word asymmetricity being used?

Comment: Some technical articles/papers in my field of research, compute architecture.

Comment: 'asymmetricity' is a word made up by people who couldn't remember the word 'asymmetry'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The addition of '-ity' to the adjective is an attempt at abstraction of the condition or quality of being asymmetric, as opposed to the mere absence of symmetry expressed as 'asymmetry'.

The word does appear on [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=asymmetricity&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Casymmetricity%3B%2Cc0) from 1948 onward, and its formation is in keeping with the traditional use of the suffix:

> [**-ity**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ity&allowed_in_frame=0)
>   
> word-forming element making abstract nouns from adjectives and meaning "condition or quality of being ______," from Middle English *-ite,* from Old French *-ete* (Modern French *-ité*) and directly from Latin *-itatem* (nominative *-itas*), suffix denoting state or condition, composed of *-i-* (from the stem or else a connective) + the common abstract suffix *-tas* (see *-ty* (2)).
>
> > Roughly, the word in *-ity* usually means the quality of being what the adjective describes, or concretely an instance of the quality, or collectively all the instances; & the word in *-ism* means the disposition, or collectively all those who feel it. [Fowler]

(Online Etymology Dictionary)

Comment: An answer with some reasonable research. +1 when you get the link right.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth:  I had no idea but it's fixed now.  Thanks for catching it!

Comment: @sumelic:  Thanks for reformatting the citation. : )

Answer (score 0):

No ! there isn't different meaning btw these 2 words. However, *asymmetricity* now is rare ; we don't use it no more except in writings, technical reports, articles to prevent repetition. But **asymmetry** is much more appropriate, light & nice...

Comment: But there is a difference.  There must be some reason that the word turns up in patent applications, of all things.

Comment: @Egox faulty analogy: electric-> electricity, asymmetric -> ??

Comment: @Egox : Beside the repetition, you'd have to find the potential nuance. Maybe, asymmetricity is the "ability" to be asymmetric, ie. a virtual asymmetry...

Comment: @Mitch: In the 1640s 'electricity' meant friction and 'electric' was used to describe substances that, like amber, would attract other substances when rubbed.  Your analogy is using 'electric' as a truncated form of 'electrical'.

Comment: @Dave:  If it is as you say, isn't ability to be asymmetric distinct from being asymmetric?

Comment: Egox : could be ! so far an ability is a potential being. Then, words are vehicules. You always use them or shape them according to your specific needs ; which is not always understood here :)

Comment: @Dave:  I see your point.  English is a living language with a limited range living affixes.  It might be easier just to create the word that you need, but the argument goes that the word is already out there.

Comment: Egox, but the world is not closed nor finished so...

Answer (score 0):

[*Asymmetry*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/asymmetry) is in the dictionary, *asymmetricity* is not. (Not in any published ones, at any rate.)

*Asymmetry* appears in the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) (COCA), *asymmetricity* does not. Not even once.

Perhaps, as another answer speculates, it's a stilted attempt to express some quality of asymmetry beyond mere lack of symmetry.